# How to pass MultiValueDict which contains file objects (django request attribute) in apache bench?

Tags: django, rest, post, image-uploading, apachebench

I am accessing the file using request.FILES in django views.

```
def upload_file(request):
    upload_files = request.FILES.getlist('myfile')
    ...
```

Can anyone please tell me how to pass a file (image/video/doc etc) in ab command, so that django view can read the file from MultiValueDict object?

Followed [this](http://www.adityamooley.net/blogs/2011/03/21/multipart-posting-with-apache-benchmark/) tutorial and checked out various posts on stack overflow

Command am using is:

```
ab -n 10 -c 2 -p /opt/file_data.txt -T "multipart/form-data; boundary=1234567890" http://localhost/app/media
```

Contents of file_data.txt are

```
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ID"

3
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

[base64 encoded file content here]
--1234567890--
```

I printed logs in django server, and am getting MultiValueDict as empty object.

Thanks for your response in advance!

Comment: So you printed out `request.FILES` and it is empty?

Comment: @WillKeeling Yes, its empty

Comment: Your `file_data.txt` file is correctly formatted with CRLF line endings? As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20224184/2091925

Comment: @WillKeeling I am not sure about that. How can I confirm it? I am using vim for editing file. I even entered \r\n manually as mentioned in that link. Still not able to figure it out.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I managed to reproduce the issue with your example `file_data.txt` and same Apache Bench command. I got an empty `request.FILES`. But then running `file_data.txt` through `unix2dos` fixed it.

Comment: @WillKeeling I ended up using Apache Jmeter. I will try with unix2dos and will post here.