# Apache bench test POST with image file contents

Tags: image, http, post, http-post, apachebench

I have a web service that accepts image files via http POST, I send them with `curl`, for example:

```
curl -X POST -F "image=@ta1.jpeg" -F "image=@ta2.jpeg" http://domain.tld/upload
```

I'm trying to test this with apache bench (`ab`) for concurrent requests. 
I see that `ab` has the option `-p` to post data but I think this requires JSON content... I tried to encode my images into JSON using the `postman` echo service :

```
curl -X POST -F "image=@ta1.jpeg" -F "image=@ta2.jpeg" http://www.postman-echo.com/post
```

save the output to file, and send that with `ab`'s `-p` option, but gen a server error.

Any hints on how to test POSTing images with apache bench?

Comment: Struggled with the same problem, found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584998/apache-benchmark-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with setting content-type?

```
ab -n 1 -p post -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded -p ta1.jpeg http://domain.tld/upload
```

When you tried to post json file, you'll want to set the json content-type:

```
ab -n 1 -p post -T application/json -p ta1.json http://domain.tld/upload
```

Comment: For both, I am getting the error `Cannot mix POST with other methods`

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Post file.

For example, create file images.txt. Ensure that the line break is CRLF

```
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="text1.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[base64 encoded image]
--1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="text2.png"
Content-Type: image/png

[base64 encoded image]
--1234567890--
```

- Script

> ab -c 1 -n 1 -v 4 -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -T "multipart/form-data; boundary=1234567890" -p "images.txt" "http://url"