# Wanted to post a video file using apache benchmark

Tags: load-testing, apachebench

I want to use apachebench (ab) to test file upload performance. I have read the manual and can't find a way to achieve my goal.

My goal is try to upload a file by a HTTPs Request with POST method and multipart/form-data format.

abs -n 10 -p test.txt -T "multipart/for-data;boundary=1234567890"https://myapplication.local/upload_file
I have tried this but getting error

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Benchmarking file uploads](https://gist.github.com/chiller/dec373004894e9c9bb38ac647c7ccfa8) and [Apache benchmark multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584998/apache-benchmark-multipart-form-data)

Just in case I'll copy the script here:

> You'll need a text file post_data.txt with the following contents:
>
> ```
> --1234567890
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ab1_pod.jpg"
> Content-Type: application/jpeg
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>
> [base64 encoding of the file]
> --1234567890--
> ```

and the call:

```
ab -n 10 -p post_data.txt -T "multipart/form-data; boundary=1234567890" https://myapplication.local/upload_file
```

Have you considered using [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)? It's way more powerful and gives you the possibility to perform the multipart file upload by just specifying the file location and ticking one box:

[image]

It also provides options to define the workload model and [powerful reporting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: i have added the text file with this content. Now i am getting .SSL read failed (1) - closing connection 30370000:error:0A000126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:321:   Please let me know what should be possible solution. I am using windows 10